# Gnuplot add arbitrary seconds column to date/time column

Tags: date, time, gnuplot

I am stumped.  I have a CSV file with a column of seconds (0 sec at beginning of file), another column with date (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`) with the following columns containing data.  I am plotting 25 Hz data (winch tension, payout) so `hh:mm` is not precise enough for plotting but I want the X-axis to still have `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`.

I can't think of an elegant way to add the seconds column to the date/time column without the x-axis label including both. Any help?

Here is a few lines of my data:

```
0.2340004,6/3/2016 20:09:09,384.0,0.0,3.4,1083.0,54.0,21.8,67.0,0.0,-0.1,,,,,,
0.2808005,6/3/2016 20:09:09,389.0,0.0,3.4,1110.0,54.0,21.9,67.0,0.0,-0.1,,,,,,
0.3276006,6/3/2016 20:09:10,397.0,0.0,3.4,1129.0,54.0,21.9,67.0,0.0,-0.1,,,,,,
0.3744007,6/3/2016 20:09:10,398.0,0.0,3.4,1149.0,54.0,21.9,67.0,0.0,-0.1,,,,,,
```

And code:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal wxt 0 
set grid  
set ls 1 lc rgb "blue" 
set ls 2 lc rgb "green"
set ls 3 lc rgb "red" 
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
set format x "%m/%d/%y\n%H:%M"
set xtics rotate by -270
set key outside above left vert Right\
 noreverse enhanced autotitle box
set ylabel "Tension (lbs)"
set y2label "Wire Out (meters)"
set yrange [-300:2200] #change to set y range
set y2range [0:*] #change to set y range

plot  'WinchDAC-6-4-2016 07-38-56#3.csv' skip 11 using 2:9 w l t 'CTD Winch Tension' ls 1 axes x1y1,\
'' skip 11 using 2:11 w l t 'Wire Out' ls 2 axes x1y2,\
(x = 2000) axes x1y1 t 'SWL 0.032" (2,000 lbs)' ls 3
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `timecolumn` function to parse the time data from the second column (the result is given in seconds since an internal reference date) and then add the seconds from the first column:

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
set format x "%m/%d/%y\n%H:%M"

file = 'WinchDAC-6-4-2016 07-38-56#3.csv' 
plot  file skip 11 using (timecolumn(2) + $1):9
```